# Use SQL functions for insert/update in ActiveRecord

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, arel

I want to store IP addresses (v4 and v6) in my rails application. I have installed [an extension to MySQL](http://labs.watchmouse.com/2009/10/extending-mysql-5-with-ipv6-functions/) adds functions to convert ip strings to binary which will allow me to query by IP range easily.

I can use unescaped sql statements for SELECT type queries, thats easy.

The hard part is that I also need a way to overwrite the way the field is escaped for insert/update statements.

This ActiveRecord statement

```
new_ip = Ip.new
new_ip.start = '1.2.3.4'
new_ip.save
```

Should generate the following SQL statement

```
INSERT INTO ips(start) VALUES(inet6_pton('1.2.3.4'));
```

Is there a way to do this? I tried many things, including overriding `ActiveRecord::Base#arel_attributes_values`, without luck : the generated sql is always converted to binary (if that matters, my column is a MySQL VARBINARY(16)).

Answer (score 0):

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("INSERT INTO ips(start) VALUES(inet6_pton('1.2.3.4'))")
```

Comment: Yeah well I would like to keep the benefits of using the regular save / create calls and everything that comes with it (validation, callbacks, etc.) if at all possibble

Comment: this also doesn't protect against SQL injection