# How can I use SQL functions when inserting with ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby, activerecord, insert, arel, sequel

With [Sequel](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net), it was easy to apply functions before inserting a row:

```ruby
the_geom_nosrid = Sequel.function :ST_GeomFromText, params[:the_geom]
the_geom_4326   = Sequel.function :ST_SetSRID,      the_geom_nosrid,  4326
the_geom_900913 = Sequel.function :ST_Transform,    the_geom_4326,    900913

DB[:drawings].returning(:id).insert the_geom: the_geom_900913
```

That would result in a query like

```sql
INSERT INTO drawings(the_geom) VALUES (ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromText(...), 4326), 900913))
```

How do I apply SQL functions when I'm inserting with [ActiveRecord](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html)? This doesn't work:

```ruby
class Drawing < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create do
    the_geom_nosrid = Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('ST_GeomFromText', [the_geom])
    the_geom_4326 = Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('ST_SetSRID', [the_geom_nosrid, 4326])
    the_geom_900913 = Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('ST_Transform', [the_geom_4326, 900913])

    # doesn't work: `Type Error: can't cast Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction to `
    # self.the_geom = the_geom_900913

    # doesn't work: tries to insert the text "ST_Transform(ST_SetSR..." into a geometry column
    # self.the_geom = Arel.sql(the_geom_900913.to_sql)
  end
end
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7148945/use-sql-functions-for-insert-update-in-activerecord

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved with the amazing [scuttle.io](http://www.scuttle.io/):

```
Drawing.create(
  :the_geom => Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new(
    'ST_Transform', [
      Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new(
        'ST_SetSRID', [
          Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('ST_GeomFromText', ['foobar']), 4326
        ]
      ), 900913
    ]
  )
)
```

Comment: can you post the SQL you pasted into scuttle?

Comment: `INSERT INTO drawings(the_geom) VALUES (ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromText('foobar'), 4326), 900913))`

Comment: Scuttle.io looks amazing-- but this logic still won't work together with before_create, right?

Comment: @dankohn would you mind showing an example? For example, I wanted to use the Arel snippet to populate an attribute on self (as shown in the original question), but got the type cast error as described above.

Comment: In your `before_create`, just replace the quoted strings and numbers with variables.